# What does soaking-out run capacitor mean?

Tags: capacitor

In the capacitor tester's manual they give several situations regarding to the reading:

> 1)If the test capacitor is a short capacitor, it will be over-range and only figure “1” is displayed
> 2)soaking-out capacitor, the reading will high its value
> 3) open-circuit capacitor, will displayed “0”. (maybe ±10pF at the 200pF range)
> 4) Display value will fluctuated, if a soaking-out capacitor connected.

What does it mean by soaking-out capacitor? Why will the reading be high in the soaking-out capacitor and why will the display value fluctuate if a soaking-out capacitor is connected?

[image]

Comment: What is the model of the capacitor tester? If you can link to the manual please do so.

Comment: Have you translated your quote because it doesn't read very well? For instance, what is a "short capacitor" + other strangeness of language.

Comment: Wild guess: wet = soaked. Wet as in wet electrolytic.

Comment: When you first connect an old electrolytic, the leakage current is very high, until the dielectric reforms. That would result in a high reading. Is this diecltric reformation phase called 'soaking out' in some languages?

Comment: @Neil_UK Incidentally, deteriorated dielectrics in dormant capacitors don't just result in leakage current but actually inflated capacitance (and lowered voltage ratings: the standard cause of death for electronic flash capacitors and power supplies of music gear powered off for decades).  With thickness of reformed dielectric getting back to normal, capacitance drops and voltage resilience rises.

Comment: Given the generally poor quality of the English translation I suspect 'soaking-out' is a poor translation of the colloquial term of a leaky capacitor, meaning one with poor insulation resistance. See user107063's comment for an explanation of why the displayed value will fluctuate.

Comment: I read the comment of user107063's,but i haven't understood yet why does a leaky capacitor cause the reading to fluctuate up and down?i understand this phrase as the reading is constantly showed as:high reading,low reading,high reading etc..while user107063 explained that the capacitance of deteriorated dielectric capacitor will rise at first,but then,after dielectric reformed the capacitance will drop,he didn't say that it will flactuate,so i haven't got it yet?

Comment: I suggest you use u/比尔盖子's translation as "unstable" rather than trying to infer anything specific from "fluctuate". If your capacitance meter allows you to place a DC bias on the capacitor under test you might expect the capacitance value to fall over time as the capacitor reforms. Without such a DC bias, and without user107063's knowledge of aging electrolytics, "unstable" is as far as I'd like to hazard a guess.

Comment: Unstable and fluctuate sound to me the same.Anyway,if there is a situation that the reading on the meter will constantly rise and fall,rise and fall...(fluctuate/unstable/jumpy),assuming that it is an electrically leakage,why is it acting like that rather only shows a steady higher value reading?(as the first situation on the manual in regards to a leaking capacitor)

Answer (score 20):

Using your screenshot, I was able to find the model number of your capacitor tester. Keep searching the model number in Chinese, I was able to find the Chinese manual of a very similar model [here](https://www.maigoo.com/citiao/249884.html).

The original text reads:

> - 当电容器短路时，仪表指示过载，并只显示“1”；
> - 当电容漏电时，显示值可以高于其真实值；
> - 当电容开路时，显示值为“0”（在200pF量程，可能显示±10pF）；
> - 当一个漏电的电容接入时，显示值可能跳动不稳定；
> - 当使用其它测试表笔来测量电容器时，表笔可能带入电容值，在测量前记下数值，并于测量后减掉。

Which can be translated to:

> - When a capacitor is shorted, meter indicates "overload", only "1" is displayed.
> - When a capacitor is (electrically) leaky, indicated value can be higher than its actual value.
> - When a capacitor is open, indicated value is "0" (at the 200-pF range, it may indicate ±10pF).
> - When a (electrically) leaky capacitor is connected, the indicated value can be "jumpy" and unstable.
> - When different test probes are used to measure a capacitor, the probes (themselves) may introduce (parasitic) capacitance. Record the capacitance before measurement, and subtract it from the measurement readout afterwards.

Thus, 'soaked-out capacitor" appears to be a mistranslation of "leaking/leaky capacitor".

Comment: Seems like your familiarity of Chinese technical terms contributed to this translation? A *leaky capacitor* could refer to **current** or to **effluent**, as suggested by two slightly different comments, and Spehro has pointed out another non-ideal property that might influence a measurement. Am curious how Chinese language might differentiate between these three non-ideal capacitor characteristics?

Comment: @glen_geek If the capacitor is leaking charges electrically, it's 漏电 (lit. leaking electricity). If the capacitor is leaking electrolyte physically, it's 漏液 (lit. leaking liquid). In this manual, it's clearly referring to the electrical case.

Comment: I would expect that for most small capacitors - i.e., the kinds of things most people would test with a cheap Amazon Chinese capacitor tester (I have one of those), if it is leaking electrolyte physically then you toss it in the trash and get a replacement - the tester is for when it looks physically OK and you want to see if it is working properly or not.

Comment: @比尔盖子,Why in one leakage case,the reading will be high value,while in the other leakage case the reading will be unstable,"jumpy"?

Answer (score 5):

It clearly refers to leakage. [Here](https://bk.lab216.com/show-9862.html) is a manual for a similar product in the original Chinese. A DeepL translation of the relevant section is as follows:

- When the capacitor is short-circuited, the meter indicates overload
  and displays only "1";
- When the capacitor leaks, the display value can be higher than its
  real value;
- When the capacitor is open-circuit, the display value is
  "0" (in 200pF range, it may display ±10pF);
- When a leaky capacitor is connected, the display value may jump and be unstable;
- When using other test pens to measure capacitors, the pens may bring in
  capacitance value, note down the value before measurement and
  subtract it after measurement.

---

That's *clearly* what is meant, however note that "soakage" is another (somewhat old-fashioned) term for [dielectric absorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_absorption), a non-ideal capacitor behaviour for which oil-filled capacitors are notorious. Most capacitors exhibit this effect to one degree or another. A symptom of DA in a dual-slope converter's integration capacitor is rollover error.

Answer (score 4):

This reads like something that has been translated back and forth from English using tools or translators not actually well-versed in the respective languages and/or electronics.

My guess at "soaking-out capacitor, the reading will high its value" is "if the capacitor has significant leakage current, the indicated capacity will be inflated".

Your best bet likely is to get the specification in the language it has originally been written in (or at least a native rendition by the person having written it in bad English) and then find someone to translate it for you (or do selective reading from several machine or dictionary translations).

Comment: good advice.., *AI translation* has improved greatly, but perhaps could improve still more for technical synonyms - 2nd-guessing AI technical translation isn't straightforward. @Neil_UK has hinted similarly.

Comment: @glen_geek Google Translate, DeepL, and even Baidu (the domestic search engine in China) provide fairly readable results for this manual, similar to my own translation by hand (as given in my answer). My best guess is that this bad translation was produced by ancient software that translates sentences one word at a time, long before today's advancement of machine learning. Taking a look at the AliExpress listing, it's obvious that a huge number of outdated translation programs are still in use today, possibly integrated in the webshop management software...